# While loop should stop when variable changes

Tags: javascript

The while loop should only run when `a < 1` but it still runs when a is incremented from 0 to 1. Why does this work at all? Shouldn't the loop stop once the variable has been incremented?

```
let a = 0;

while (a < 1) {
  console.log('a = 0');
  while (a === 0) {
    console.log('a still = 0')
    a++
  }
  console.log('a = 1'); // why does this run ?
}
```

Comment: That's coz you increment it in the inner while, after which it becomes 1 and the condition evaluates to false. After the second console.log only, will the outer condition be evaluated.

Comment: the first while will be fully executed, use break to stop it

Comment: The outer loop will complete regardless of what value you set to `a` in the inner loop....it just won't run again if condition is not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk it through. `a` starts as 0. Is it < 1? Yes. Print "a = 0". Is it === 0? Yes. Print "a still = 0". Add 1 to `a`. Now it is 1. Loop. Is it === 0? No. Print "a = 1".

*The loop condition is only checked at the start of each iteration.* A new iteration starts whenever it hits the closing `}`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've incremented `a` in your inner loop but you're still inside your outer loop!

So for example:

```
while (a < 1) {
  console.log('a = 0');
  
  while (a === 0) {
    console.log('a still = 0')
    a++ // now a = 1
  }
  console.log('a = 1'); // a != 0 so we exit the inner loop and move back to the outer loop
// BUT we are still in the same (first) iteration
}
```

Notice that if you change the first condition to `a < 2`, that last console log (`a = 1`) will print in an infinite loop. This is because once `a` is incremented so that `a = 1` it never hits the inside loop and a never increments. So `a` will always be 1 and subsequently `a` will always be less than two, causing the while loop to print forever

Answer (score 0):

console.log ('a = 1'); is still processed after the variable a value is incremented. More, while a <1 already includes while a === 0, so while a === 0 should be deleted.

```
let a = 0;

while (a < 1) {
  console.log("value a before incrementation");
  console.log(a);
  //handle code
  a++;
  console.log("value a after incrementation");
  console.log(a);
}
```